# How to specify column width for first column using react-table

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7, react-table-v6

When using `useRowSelect` and `useTable` how can I specify column width for the first column so that it never exceeds the width of the checkboxes? I don't want to use `useFlex` as I want to preserve column widths based on the header width.

You'll notice when the table is set to 100% width the first column starts to grow if you expand your browser window.

Here's an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-hamilton-j0rev?file=/src/App.js

I'm also open to just grabbing the Header and Cell from where I'm pushing into the columns array and adding a className, but wasn't able to find a way to do that. How can I add a className so that the table cell that surrounds this column data has a className to attach to:

```
    (hooks) => {
      isRowSelectable &&
        hooks.allColumns.push((columns) => [
          {
            id: 'selection',
            minWidth: 35,
            width: '35px',
            maxWidth: 35,
            Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
              <Checkbox alignSelf="center" {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            ),
            Cell: ({ row }: any) => {
              row.className = '123';
              return <Checkbox alignSelf="center" {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />;
            }
          },
          ...columns
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Array.map` can pass the index of the element, it's fairly simple to conditionally add a className to the cell if the row index is 0:

```
{
  rows.map((row, i) => {
    prepareRow(row);
    return (
      <td className={i === 0 ? "class-name" : ""} {...cell.getCellProps()>
         {cell.render("Cell")}
      </td>
    ) ​
}
```

If you want the same class to apply to the headers, you can do the same thing on the `<th>` or `<tr>` elements, since those are also rendered with `Array.map`. You don't actually need to touch the `columns` object at all for this change.